# GitHub Pages URL converts "/" to "-"

Tags: github, github-pages, git-bash

I'm trying to host my website at `username.github.io/projectname` but it is coming as `username.github.io-projectname`. The `/` is getting converted to `-`.

After pushing the data to repository I get a 404 error when trying to visit the website. How can I properly host my project site on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I'm trying to host my website using "username.github.io/projectname", it is coming as "username.github.io-projectname". The "/" is getting converted to "-".

In this case your repository should simply be called `projectname`. The `username` part is done automatically. Your website's code should be put in

- a branch called `gh-pages`,
- a branch called `master`, or
- a `docs/` folder in your `master` branch.

This [is configurable](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).